# Could there be an easier way to use pandas read_clipboard to read a Series?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, clipboard, series

Some times, i want use `read_clipboard` to read `Series`es, and i would have to do:

```
pd.Series(pd.read_clipboard(header=None).values[:,0])
```

So would it be nice if there was an easier way?

I can do it very easily for data-frames, like:

```
pd.read_clipboard()
```

And that's it.

But for `Series`, it's much longer-one-liner.

So is there an easier way?

That i don't know?

Any secretive code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Copy this to clipboard:

```
1
2
3
```

Better would be to use `squeeze=True` as an argument.

```
pd.read_clipboard(header=None, squeeze=True)

0    1
1    2
2    3
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

Which returns a `Series`.  If you want to name the series, use the `names` parameter:

```
pd.read_clipboard(header=None, squeeze=True, names=['mycol'])

0    1
1    2
2    3
Name: mycol, dtype: int64
```

Actually, `read_clipboard` uses pyperclip to read from the clipboard, and sends the text to [`read_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_table.html).

Read up on the supported arguments.

Comment: That's very nice, this would be probably better than jezrael's.

Comment: @U9-Forward Let `read_table` do as much of the dirty work for you as possible.

Comment: Wow, even better to do a name

Comment: @U9-Forward All the parameters are documented in `read_table`, although I can understand remembering them all can be a pain in the arse.

Comment: Lol, :-) yup, :D

Answer (score 2):

I think simplest is remove `Series` constructor ([`read_clipboard`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_clipboard.html) return here one column `DataFrame`) and because `header` is `None` always column is `0`:

```
s = pd.read_clipboard(header=None)[0]
```

Another solution with [`DataFrame.squeeze`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.squeeze.html) for pandas 0.20.0+ for converting one column `DataFrame` to `Series`:

```
s = pd.read_clipboard(header=None).squeeze()
```

Comment: That's simpler!! cool, that's easy, but beating my brains out and couldn't find that.

Comment: Thought me `squeeze`, even tho i am unable to use it due to my version.