# How can I effectively load data on Stack Overflow questions using Pandas read_clipboard?

Tags: python, pandas, clipboard

I notice a lot of Pandas questions on Stack Overflow only include a few rows of their data as text, without the accompanying code to generate/reproduce it. I am aware of the existence of [`read_clipboard`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_clipboard.html), but I am unable to figure out how to effectively call this function to read data in many situations, such as when there are white spaces in the header names, or Python objects such as lists in the columns.

How can I use `pd.read_clipboard` more effectively to read data pasted in unconventional formats that don't lend themselves to easy reading using the default arguments? Are there situations where `read_clipboard` comes up short?

Comment: Made sure main was the right place to post this by asking [a question on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403870/should-my-canonical-about-read-clipboard-usage-in-pandas-be-on-meta-or-main/403875?noredirect=1#comment815449_403875).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## [`read_clipboard`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_clipboard.html): Beginner's Guide

---

[`read_clipboard`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#id45) is truly a saving grace for anyone starting out to answer questions in the [Pandas tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas). Unfortunately, pandas veterans also know that the data provided in questions isn't always easy to grok into a terminal due to various complications in the format of the data posted.

Thankfully, `read_clipboard` has arguments that make handling most of these cases possible (and easy). Here are some common use cases and their corresponding arguments.

---

### Common Use Cases

`read_clipboard` uses `read_csv` under the hood with white space separator, so a lot of the techniques for parsing data from CSV apply here, such as

- **parsing columns with spaces in the data**

  - use `sep` with regex argument. First, ensure there are at least two spaces between columns and at most one consecutive white space inside the column's data itself. Then you can use `sep=r'\s{2,}'` which means "separate columns by looking for at least two consecutive white spaces for the separator" (note: `engine='python'` is required for multicharacter or regex separators):

    ```
     df = pd.read_clipboard(..., sep=r'\s{2,}', engine='python')
    ```

    Also see [How do you handle column names having spaces in them when using pd.read_clipboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45528198/how-do-you-handle-column-names-having-spaces-in-them-when-using-pd-read-clipboar).
- **reading a series instead of DataFrame**

  - use `squeeze=true`, you would likely also need `header=None` if the first row is also data.

    ```
     s = pd.read_clipboard(..., header=None, squeeze=True)
    ```

    Also see [Could there be an easier way to use pandas read_clipboard to read a Series?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54021079/4909087).
- **loading data with custom header names**

  - use `names=[...]` in conjunction with `header=None` and `skiprows=[0]` to ignore existing headers.

    ```
     df = pd.read_clipboard(..., header=None, names=['a', 'b', 'c'], skiprows=[0])
    ```
- **loading data without any headers**

  - use `header=None`
- **set one or more columns as the index**

  - use `index_col=[...]` with the appropriate label or index
- **parsing dates**

  - use `parse_dates` with the appropriate format. If parsing `datetimes` (i.e., columns with date separated by timestamp), you will likely also need to use `sep=r'\s{2,}'` while ensuring your columns are separated by at least two spaces.

See [this answer by me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56231664/4909087) for a more comprehensive list on `read_csv` arguments for other cases not covered here.

---

### Caveats

`read_clipboard` is a Swiss Army knife. However, it

- cannot read data in prettytable/tabulate formats (IOW, borders make it harder)

  - See [Reading in a pretty-printed/formatted dataframe using pd.read_clipboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45856926/4909087) for solutions to tackle this.
- cannot correctly parse MultIndexes unless all elements in the index are specified.

  - See [Copying MultiIndex dataframes with pd.read_clipboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45740537/4909087) for solutions to tackle this.
- cannot ignore/handle ellipses in data

  - my suggested method is to manually remove ellipses before printing
- cannot parse columns of lists (or other objects) as anything other than string. The columns will need to be converted separately, as shown in [How do you read in a dataframe with lists using pd.read_clipboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45827372/4909087).
- cannot read text from images (so please don't use images as a means to share your data with folks, please!)

Answer (score 2):

The one weakness of this function is that it doesn't capture contents of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> if the copy is performed from a [PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format) file. Testing it this way results in an empty read.

But by using a regular text editor, it goes just fine. Here is an example using randomly typed text:

```
>>> pd.read_clipboard()
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [sfsesfsdsxcvfsdf]
Index: []
```

Comment: Hopefully no one is going around pasting pdfs of their data for folks to use while answering questions here, but this is a general concern. Well, this, and being unable to parse text from images, which are all too commonly posted on this site. :-( If you're up to make a tesseract extension that does this, you'll be doing a pretty big service.

Comment: That's something to look into. I have never worked with tesseract but always up to learn something new. Thanks @cs95!